# Stop displaying the name field from displaying on a wiki page

Tags: wiki-pages

I've just started a new wiki library.  and I have page called "`tags`" which describes how to tag a file.

The name of the file is "`tags.aspx`",
The heading on the page is: "`How to use tags`"

I would like to stop displaying "`tags`" on the top of the page.

Is there script editor option here?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand from you. you have A `wiki library` with a page called `tags` with heading on the page is: "`How to use tags`" as the following

[image]

and you need to hide page name that called in this case `Tags`.

Regarding **Is there script editor option here?**

You can add a content editor but you will face an issue to add HTML source as normal page so try to use the following steps to achieve adding `content editor` for `wiki` page

**Steps:**

- create a new `CSS` file.
- Add the following `CSS` code

> ```
> <style>    
> #DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea {
>         display: none ! important;
>     }
> </style>
> ```

Or this with  the URL of your page.

> ```
> <style>
> a[href='/workflow/tags/tags.aspx']{ display: none ! important; } 
> </style>
> ```

- Upload it to any library at your site .
- Get its URL as the following.

[image]

- Go to your wiki page.
- Edit Page.
- Add Content Editor
- Edit Webpart
- Paste the link of `CSS` file.
  [image]
- also at appearance set chrome type to `None`
- Save the page.

The output should be like this.

[image]